# perform javascript event when url entered in the textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a `showPreview` option for an entered URL on my site just like Facebook shows a preview of the URL.

When the User enters the url, the following condition gets verified:

```
$('#text').keyup(function(e) {
            allowPosting = true;
    if ((e.which === 13 || e.which === 32 || e.which === 17) && trim($(this).val()) !== "") 
}
```

Key code:

```
13 - Enter
45 - Insert
17 - control
```

Now the function is being called when the user **copy and pastes the URL** or **Selects the URL from the preview and presses Enter key**

**What I want:**

The preview should be shown if the user types in the URL, even if the user does not press the enter key or copy and pastes the URL.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, this will do everything you wrote:

```
 $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
    allowPosting = true;
    if (/(^|\s)((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9!*'();:@&=+$,\/?#[\]\-_.~]+)/.test($("#text").val()) && trim($(this).val()) !== "")
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
});
```

It will also check if the input is a link or not, so that the user can enter "http://google.com/" and not e.g. "asdf"!

Answer (score 1):

check the .val() after every keyup, not only on Enter, and if it is an URL, do the rest

Answer (score 1):

Try change in place of keyup :

```
$('#text').change(function(){...});
```